# In R, Coefficients of MA Function Are Wrong?

Tags: r, math, time-series

I'm currently sifting through my copy of Analysis of Financial Time Series 2nd Edition by Ruey Tsay, and one of the sections involves fitting a MA model to certain data (data set is [here](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/ruey.tsay/teaching/fts/m-ew.dat)). Here's the fit with exact maximum likelihood according to the text, with certain insignificant parameters removed:

rt = 0.013 + a(t) + 0.181a(t−1) − 0.121a(t−3) + 0.122a(t−9)

σ(a) = 0.0724

However, when I try to fit it with R...

```
> mew = read.table("m-ew.dat")
> arima(mew,order = c(0,0,9),fixed = c(NA,0,NA,rep(0,5),NA,NA),method = "ML")
Call:
arima(x = mew, order = c(0, 0, 9), fixed = c(NA, 0, NA, rep(0, 5), NA, NA), 
method = "ML")

Coefficients:
        ma1  ma2      ma3  ma4  ma5  ma6  ma7  ma8     ma9  intercept
      0.180    0  -0.1318    0    0    0    0    0  0.1373     0.0132
s.e.  0.031    0   0.0362    0    0    0    0    0  0.0327     0.0029

sigma^2 estimated as 0.005282:  log likelihood = 1039.1,  aic = -2068.21
```

As you can see, the ma1 coefficients are the same, but ma3 and ma9 are different, even with method = "ML", i.e. maximum likelihood. Why is this?

Also, from a practical standpoint, while ma2 and ma4-ma8 may be 0 (their 95% confidence intervals overlap with 0), removing them from the model raises the AIC, lowers the p-value with regards to the Ljung-Box test on the residuals, and also lowers the log-likelihood value. Is it even worth removing these parameters if such things happen?

Answer (score 2):

In the help to arima one can read:
"The results are likely to be different from S-PLUS's arima.mle, which computes a conditional likelihood and does not include a mean in the model. Further..."

and Tsay uses S-Plus...

Comment: Thanks! Absolutely, I'm just wondering where the difference originates. As it turns out, the conditional likelihood and exact likelihood estimates yield practically the same results for any data set of this size, R uses exact likelihood though whereas it appears S-Plus with its arima modeling uses the conditional. However, R is still quite similar to S-Plus. As it turns out, the data is missing about 6 years' worth of information (it only goes up to 1997 whereas Tsay in the book refers to the model up through 2003) - that's probably where the difference comes from.